# Does WordPress avoids arrays on wp_insert_post_data filter?

Tags: wordpress, http-post

I'm using wp_insert_post_data filter hook to save some extra data which I get from a meta box in a custom post type. I want to save these extra data as the post_content not the post_meta_data.
There is a select box with Select2 which is possible to select more than one values (pillbox). Finally Select2 prepares an array of values. I've checked browser Network section and the value is an array but when I try to access the value in wp_insert_post_data, I just get the last item of the array as an string and not an array!

Here is my function :

```
function xxx_save_country_data(array $data): array
{

    $countries = $_POST['xxx_countries_field']; //It should be an array but it is only string

    return $data;

}

add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'xxx_save_country_data');
```

Posted data screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kX97.png

Answer (score 0):

In my plugin case, I'm using woocommerce_form_field to generate the select element and if you don't specify `id` parameter as the `$args` in this function, both id and name properties get the same string and so it becomes `xxx_countries_field` and not `xxx_countries_field[]` which was the problem!